# Почему записи модели отображаются одновременно

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-model

Тут такое дело, мне нужно что бы на странице отображалось последние записи модели, для этого я добавил в моделях новую запись pub_date что бы добавить в очередь записи, но как и предсказывалось ничего не работает и записи отображаются одновременно, то есть вместе

код models.py

```
class Avaibility(models.Model):
name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
apply_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
presence_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.apply_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.presence_text
```

код views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def description(self):
    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    numbers = Number.objects.all()
    context['numbers'] = numbers
    return context

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context['avaibilitys'] = avaibilitys
    return context
```

если ещё что-то понадобится пишите добавлю любую инфу

так же, вот что в итоге отображает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так он и будет выводить все. вы же просто сортируете по дате.

если надо сколько-то конкретно, так и укажите, например дай три последних

```
avaibilitys = Avaibility.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:3]
```

Comment: Tatarincev спасибо но теперь как сделать что бы на разных блоках отображались разные записи ?

Comment: дальше уже прописывайте в шаблоне где-что выводить

Comment: Tatarincev Вот так ? "<td class="hoh">{{ avaibility.presence1_text }}</td>"